# Which packages in Atom make the same features in Sublime

Tags: editor, atom-editor

I have use Sublime 3 for a while, and then I decided to use Atom, but by default it doesn't have the same features as Sublime 3.

Which are all the packages and themes do I have to install to make the Atom work as Sublime 3

For example, the right-hand map to see all code, the multiple cursor, and so on.

Comment: If you're looking for an editor that works like Sublime, why not Sublime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "minimap" package for the mini map like sublime
For "painting" the code you should try monokai and seti-ui

Answer (score 2):

1. [Minimap](https://atom.io/packages/minimap)

   - Adds a small preview of your full source code
2. [Set syntax](https://atom.io/packages/set-syntax)

   - Creates easy Command Palette commands for setting the syntax of the current file
3. [Highlight selected](https://atom.io/packages/highlight-selected)

   - When double clicking on a word, it highlights the current word selected & all of other occurrences in a file
4. [sublime-style-column-selection](https://atom.io/packages/sublime-style-column-selection)

   - Enable Sublime style 'Column Selection'. Just hold 'alt' while you select, or select using your middle mouse button. Also similar to Texmate's 'Multiple Carets', or BBEdit's 'Block Select'

5.[Browse](https://atom.io/packages/browse)

- Add dialog to browse packages folder (like in Sublime Text)

6.[Sublime-block-comment](https://atom.io/packages/sublime-block-comment)

- Toggle block comments like in Sublime Text

7.[Zen](https://atom.io/packages/Zen)

- Distraction free writing mode, similiar to Sublime's Distraction Free mode

8.[Pane Layout Plus](https://atom.io/packages/pane-layout-plus)

- "Sublime Text-like n-column layout shortcuts."

9.[Package settings](https://atom.io/packages/package-settings)

- quickly open settings pane for a specific package from the command-pallete

10.[Sort lines](https://atom.io/packages/sort-lines)

- Sorts the current highlighted selection.

If you'd like to see some of these packages & more in action, check out this short YouTube video about Atom : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFAzqvYoHJs